# React Axios Input Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I must post {input} data to http://localhost:4000/prediction with Axios. But {input} turns undefined.

I am using const instead of class Main extends component. onChange, it sets form data.

```
const Main = ({ value, suggestions, auth: { user } }) => {

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState("");

  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  const { input } = formData;

  const onChange = e => setFormData(e.target.value);

  const onSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setMessages(prevMsgs => [...prevMsgs, formData]);

    console.log({ input });
```

Axios post.

```
    axios
      .post(
        `http://localhost:4000/prediction`,
        { input },
        { crossdomain: true }
      )
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        //setMessages(prevMsgs => [...prevMsgs, formData]);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
  };
```

Return (form) with onSubmit, onChange.

```
  return (
    <div className="true">
      <br />
      <form noValidate onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
        <div className="input-group mb-3">
           <input
                name="input"
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Type text"
                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              />
            )}
          <div className="input-group-append">
            <button className="btn btn-outline-secondary">Send</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: `formData` is a string as I see which does not have a property called `input` what you try to destructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have mentioned in the comment section `formData` is a string as I see which does not have a property called `input` what you try to destructure and that's why it is `undefined` always.

If you really need that format for **axios** then you can try change the structure of `formData` with `useState` as the following first:

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({input: null});
```

Then maybe you can try updating as:

```
const onChange = e => setFormData({input: e.target.value});
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but one more thing. Can't we really make the input "form data"? How can I set {input} to form data? `const data = new FormData();
  data.set("input", { input });` didn't work well.